# Null ClientCertificate when doing simultaneous requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, https

I have an application that uses SSL Mutual Authentication and I noticed an issue where parallel REST requests resulted in a null response from Request.GetClientCertificate.

I created an empty ASP.NET Web Application to isolate another factors and got the same result. These are the files involved

Index.html

```
<script src="~/Scripts/testing.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <button onclick="x()">Test</button>
</div>
```

testing.js

```js
function x() {
    // Making two simultaneous requests 
    $.ajax({
        url: "api/values"
    }).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "api/values"
    }).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

ValuesController.cs

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebTemp.Controllers {
    public class ValuesController : ApiController {
        // GET api/values
        public string Get() {
            var cert = Request.GetClientCertificate(); // Here I get null in one of the requests

            return cert == null ? "null" : cert.SubjectName.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the button on html, calling both ajax at the same time, I get a null from one call and the correct certificate value from the other. 
The problem does not occur if I call one ajax only after the other has returned.

I also noticed the error happens on Chrome, but the code works correctly on Edge.